# Challenges with Lifetime Specifiers and Attribute Macros in Solana Playground: Seeking Guidance

Tags: anchor, lifetimes

Hello Solana Community,

I'm developing a smart contract using Solana Playground (beta.solpg.io), and I've encountered several compilation errors that I'm struggling to resolve. My contract involves implementing a game logic with SPL tokens, but specific Rust and Anchor framework nuances are posing challenges. Below are the key errors:

1. Lifetime Specifiers: Errors related to missing lifetime specifiers in the `#[program]` macro (`error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier`). I'm uncertain how to correctly apply lifetime specifiers in this context.
2. Invalid Attribute: The compiler cannot find the `state` attribute (`error: cannot find attribute 'state' in this scope`).
3. Unresolved Imports: Issues with unresolved imports and incorrect usage of `ID` values, likely due to my misunderstanding of proper import statements from Anchor and Solana libraries.
4. Type Alias Confusion: Errors indicating a mismatch in generic arguments for `Result` (`error[E0107]: this type alias takes 1 generic argument but 2 generic arguments were supplied`).
5. Private Function Accessibility: The functions `update_balances` and `emit_game_result_event` are flagged as private, preventing their use (`error[E0603]: function '...' is private`).

I've tried addressing these by revising import statements and adjusting the use of macros and type aliases, but with limited success. The complexity of Anchor's macros combined with Rust's strict type system makes pinpointing the exact causes challenging, especially in the constrained environment of Solana Playground.

Any insights, examples, or resources on how to navigate these issues, especially in the context of Solana's Rust-based framework, would be incredibly helpful.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!

Answer (score 2):

1. Lifetime errors might be happening due to variety of reasons which makes it hard to give an answer without seeing the code. If you'd like to learn more about lifetimes, [Validating References with Lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html) section of the Rust Book is a great resource.
2. `#[state]` attribute macro has been removed in `anchor-lang 0.27.0`.

The remaining errors are most likely caused by the first and second errors — this means fixing the first and second errors will most likely fix the remaining errors too.